# JavaScript: Finding a difference between two dates in years

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

I've got two TimeStamps e1 and e2 (both expressed in milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970). I want to know what is the difference between them in years (including parts of years - e.g. 2.74 is an acceptable result).

Dividing (e2 - e1) by 31536000000 is not the right idea because of leap years. Is there an elegant solution ?

Comment: new Date(e2).getFullYear() - new Date(e1).getFullYear() is good enough?

Comment: Aren't leap days also a part of the year?

Comment: getFullYear won't work, as it return only integral number of years.
Leap days are indeed parts of the year, but I'd like for e.g. e2 = 28-Feb-2014, e1 = 28-Feb-2012 to get '2', not 2.002... (because of 29-Feb-2012).

Comment: It makes sense logically that you would want 2, not 2.002 - but from the point of view of counting/math this is not ok, since if we count years we assume they are all the same - e.g. from 28-Feb-2000 to 28-Feb-2002 you get the same number of years as in your example (e2 = 28-Feb-2014, e1 = 28-Feb-2012) but 1 day less.

Since the week is the largest regular time period i would recommend measuring in weeks. That would be (e2-e1) / (3600*24*7*1000). Otherwise i'm afraid you'd have to check for leap years manually somehow.

Comment: If you run the following code:

var d=new Date(2012,1,29,0,0,0,0);
d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()+1);
alert(d.toString());

You will get the first of March next year. So it would be possible to add exactly one year to any date. Maybe this helps you in finding an algorithm (unfortunately you can't add 0.5 years).

Comment: OK - thanks for help :). That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas in your comment are nice. However, you just need to determine if only one of timestamps is a leap year. Then simple find what difference is between first date and second date, by comparing timestamps without years. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/EN8qG/

```
function compareYears(t1, t2) {
    var DAY = 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        YEAR = 365 * DAY,
        d1 = new Date(t1),
        d2 = new Date(t2),
        y1 = d1.getFullYear(),
        y2 = d2.getFullYear(),
        isLeap1 = new Date(y1, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1,
        isLeap2 = new Date(y2, 1, 29).getMonth() == 1,
        ms1 = t1 - Date.UTC(y1, 0, 0),
        ms2 = t2 - Date.UTC(y2, 0, 0),
        diff = ms2 - ms1,
        rest;

    if (isLeap1 && isLeap2) { //two leap years
        rest = diff / YEAR;
    } else if (isLeap1) { 
        rest = diff / (YEAR + DAY);
    } else if (isLeap2) { 
        rest = diff / (YEAR + DAY);
    } else {
        rest = diff / YEAR;
    }
    return y2 - y1 + rest;
}
```